# Loopable audio in Java

Tags: java, loops, audio

I have this code for playing audio files is Java

```
File file = new File(sfxPath);
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
clip.start();
```

How can I make it loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Clip::loop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#loop(int)):

```java
clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); // or however many times you want it to loop
```